# C# HTTPS GET and POST with COOKIE

Tags: c#, http, cookies, https

I want to use some REST API shared for my client where it's required two requests in one shot or something like that. I can't get documentation from client so I need to resolve this problem by myself.

So, what I want to achive:
if I send request by Insomnia (something like postman), I'm getting stacktrace like below

```
* Preparing request to https://api.censored_api.com/api/test
* Current time is 2023-02-10T21:32:05.491Z
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Using default HTTP version
* Enable timeout of 30000ms
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 2 cookies
*   Trying 111.111.111.88:443...
* Connected to api.censored_api.com (111.111.111.88) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
CN=www.censored_api.com
*  start date: Dec  6 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 14 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.censored_api.com" matched cert's "api.censored_api.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1d5fa281de0)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

> GET /api/test HTTP/2
> Host: api.censored_api.com
> user-agent: insomnia/2022.7.5
> accept: */*

* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< server: Kestrel
< lang: en
< srctype: default
< rid: 64c619b5-0e3f-4ac9-9a69-3d6b2657014e
< gid: 102
< x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt: 5
< x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency: 192
< expires: Fri, 10 Feb 2023 21:32:06 GMT
< cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< pragma: no-cache
< date: Fri, 10 Feb 2023 21:32:06 GMT
< strict-transport-security: max-age=86400
< set-cookie: bmtf=2B19763A78567D483337DEEFB95CEEEF~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQrIfdWBS4DDiGAQAA3Bw+PRI3JD7HGcbuLAJM36p53BaHdmMTjHNHIMvdFBAZ3dKYeeQPonmJ0OrCqK4G8pQhdkfnpEY8zWZi/fEhsiYkICnaRAk3linKO82YMdggBDZsyEONtwKmmIPH2PHyb/wJvTasPxIblGSb5QTEG03tcJuzMPwlxEbKTGdSvrqp1o+tk36qsn/aCKMBA1zsaTeKI2uPgTDBgFW67h+nxZKP0iGFfiQ4w+Vg1J485FUEAQ1RgHpkXtWUF1CwbFUkoESPawW81Euygm4+ExLWgPQa9tOCNG9xW2RsvENZzPDMXWfq8/DfSCrdJ89GVAC8e0kZI9cSZ7jVFtdvI5GoDCoRWwyp4L5aLhr1K03gurLu6owTf1XpmjpcP1s=; Domain=.censored_api.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 10 Feb 2023 23:32:05 GMT; Max-Age=7199; HttpOnly


* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Received 3.2 KB chunk
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Received 4 KB chunk
```

So what I made is:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://api.censored_api.com");
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync("/api/test");
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
```

But after 100s I'm getting timeout and I don't know what can I do other.

What's funny, I made the same request in python and it's working perfectly, but I need this in c#.

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.censored_api.com")

payload = ""

headers = { 'cookie': "" }

conn.request("GET", "/api/test", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

f = open("result.txt", "a")
f.write(data.decode("utf-8"))
f.close()
```

Do you have some idea how to implement this in C#?

Wireshark result:
(under white block I hide my IP, under orange block is api IP)
[image: Wireshark result]

Comment: what do you mean by "But after 100s I'm getting timeout" are you using this in a loop or something?

Comment: No, in line 'var result = await client.GetAsync("/api/test");' it's waiting for respone but after 100s I'm getting System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.'

Comment: if you are going to call this a lot you should move `HttpClient`  out of the method

Comment: Can you use other endpoints from the same API?

Comment: Does it work without the cookie container?

Comment: If you just want to increase the timeout, then set `HttpClient.Timeout`.

Comment: for start I just want to make example request to get data. No, for now I have only one endpoint. Endpoint which I wrote in question is fake, becouse I can't show you origin url.

Comment: No, without the cookie container is also doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have problem with timeout, I have problem with connection, the request get setting up cookies and then by using POST fetching data, but it's in one GET request from client.

Comment: Are you sure you are successfully sending the request? step through with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that request was sent. I was using Wireshark to check what's going on and I saw outgoing package.

Comment: what do you mean await inside a lock?

Comment: You would know if you were trying to do it don't worry about that, If the server just doesn't respond and doesn't send an error code its hard to know what is wrong.

Comment: You are awaiting the result so you could use the debugger to see if there was any kind of response or if you were just ignored

Comment: Do you see any kind of response in wireshark?

Comment: I posted wireshark result, which Im catching, in question, you can see what Im getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because you aren't supplying a user agent based on your other answer and the lack of one in your question.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "SomeUserAgentYouCanSetThisToAnything");
```

or

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("SomeUserAgentYouCanSetThisToAnything");
```

Combined with my other suggestion to move `HttpClient` out of the method this might work.

Your wireshark image shows that the server is just ignoring you `len=0` after completing the handshake, So some firewall is probably blocking the default `user-agent` (or lack of one) or something like that.

If `WebRequest` works there is no reason not to use that.

Answer (score 0):

It's intersting, I use WebRequest and when I set UserAgent like postman it start working.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UserAgent = "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2";
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Timeout = 30 * 1000;  // 60 second timeout

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```